# Android emulator showing black bars on screen

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-emulator, xfce

I am running android emulators on an ubuntu machine running the XFCE desktop.

The emulators have hardware selected for graphics.

When I use the emulators they sometimes show black bars over the screen and I am wondering how to troubleshoot / resolve this. Below is a picture of the issue.

[image]

Comment: Try another DE to confirm if this is an Xfce issue. Also try another video driver.

Comment: The same issue happens with gnome too